# "Domain join directory" using aws ec2 cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

While launching the AWS EC2 instance from AWS Console (old console) there is an option in Step 3 to join the instance in "Domain join directory" (screenshot attached)

[image]

Is there a way to "Domain join directory" using "aws ec2 run-instance" cli
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Any help much appreciated.